# How to disconnect login signals from Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am implementing custom authentication in Django v 2.2.7. I'd like to disconnect django default login signals. How Can I do it? And where should the code live? See [login source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/contrib/auth/#login)

Specifically: Disconnect the user_logged_in signal from update_last_login receiver

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/#disconnecting-signals

`Signal.disconnect(receiver=None, sender=None, dispatch_uid=None)`